# How to force Razor to make Editorfor to input number type for float variable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-input, editorformodel

Here is my code in MVC 5:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.myfloatvalue, new { @type = "number", @min = "0", @step = "0.01", @value = "0" })
```

And here is the html code:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Fix Amount must be a number." data-val-required="The Fix Amount field is required." id="myfloatvalue" name="myfloatvalue" type="text" value="">
```

Not to

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Fix Amount must be a number." data-val-required="The Fix Amount field is required." id="myfloatvalue" name="myfloatvalue" type="number" min="0" step="0.01" value="0">
```

What should I do?

Thanks for response!

Comment: You cannot add html attributes to `EditorFor()` that way (and not at all unless your using MVC-5.1 or higher). Change it to `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.myfloatvalue, new { type = "number, min = 0, .... })`

Comment: but TextBoxFor returns null when I click Submit button.

Comment: What do you mean? The `@TextBoxFor()` method render a `<input type="text" ../>` exactly as `@EditorFor()` would have (except you can add the html attributes)

Comment: Yes you are right. If I post the current Model as the Model pattern it works. I was posting inputs one be one.

Comment: And why are you setting `value = "0"`? You should **never** set the `value` attribute when using the html helpers.

Comment: Please write your suggestion as an answer !

Comment: Slicsim added an answer assuming you were using MVC-5.1 (showing the correct syntax), so I'll just edit that answer so you can accept it.

Comment: TextBoxFor works now. I was posting input by its name. Now I post **public ActionResult NewFee(Fee fee)** instead of **public ActionResult NewFee(float feevalue)**

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Posting back the model is the correct approach, but it would have bound if you used `public ActionResult NewFee(float myfloatvalue)` because the name of your input is `myfloatvalue`, not `feevalue`

Comment: I was setting a name as **@name=feevalue** for the TextBoxFor

Comment: I must pass the model itself instead of the input

Comment: You cannot override the `name` attribute that way - look at the html your generating - it has `name="myfloatvalue"`, not `name="feevalue"` despite your attempt. And fortunately it does not work otherwise you would screw up model binding

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks for response!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping your anonymous object in the `htmlAttributes` of another anonymous object?  When using `EditorFor`/`TextBoxFor`, I believe in MVC 5 that's the only way of affecting the HTML attributes output by the editor.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.myfloatvalue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "number", @min = "0", @step = "0.01", @value = "0" }})
```

If you not using MVC-5.1 or higher, then you will need to use `TextBoxFor()`.
Note no `htmlAttributes` used here:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.myfloatvalue, new { type = "number", min = "0", step = "0.01" }) // don't set the value attribute
```

Comment: Support for htmlAttributes was added in mvc 5.1, what version are you running?

Comment: The version of DLL is 4.0.0.0

Comment: If you look in the web.config at the assembly redirects for System.Web.Mvc, what version of the dll is redirecting to?  In mine its 5.2.2.0.  The code above works in that version.  You might need to upgrade your project to a later version of mvc, or switch back to a textboxfor, or possible try the UiHint attribute on your model

Comment: This doens't seem to work in IE, but works great for chrome

Comment: You have a duplicate brace in the second example `}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can actually change the default behaviour for the EditorFor for a `float` so that it produces `type="number"` instead of `type="text"`.

To do that you need to add a custom `EditorTemplate` for the `Single` (**not** `float`) type to `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Single.cshtml` as follows:

```
@model Single?

@{
    var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(ViewData["htmlAttributes"]);
    if (!attributes.ContainsKey("type")) { attributes.Add("type", "number"); }
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, attributes)
```

The reason this works is that `float` is a C# alias for `System.Single` (see the [Microsoft c# Language Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/float) for more details on that).  Adding an `EditorTemplate` called Float.cshtml will not work (I tried...).

I got the idea for this from @[Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke)'s excellent answer [to my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018727/make-editorfor-render-decimal-value-as-type-text-not-type-number).  He also mentions the idea of creating your own `HtmlHelper` extension so you could then write `@Html.FloatFor(...)`.

This same approach can also be applied to `Decimal` and `Double`, both of which also render `type="text"` by default.