# need help: editor and numbers asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, numbers, editor

I have an editor field in asp.net which needs to be integer input only between 1 and the size of a list. Atm i got this as code

> @Html.Editor("Prioriteit" + item, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "number", min = "0",step = "1", value = "0" } })

this isn't to the maximum of the list, I know this. However when i open the page i can still add text.
[View with text in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pxiz.png)
Someone can help me out?
thanks in advance
Changed the code for the sake of someone linking it to another question
code

```
        @Html.TextBox("Prioriteit" + item,null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "number", min = "0",step = "1", value = "0" } })
```

[still the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsZKF.png)
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force Razor to make Editorfor to input number type for float variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755560/how-to-force-razor-to-make-editorfor-to-input-number-type-for-float-variable)

Comment: Solutions from there are not helping me. Already tried it before posting this...

Comment: Is there any particular reason you use the helper methods? And dont just use `<input type="number" min="0" step="1" value="0" name="Prioriteit@item" />`

Comment: didn't knew that was possible, thank you for solving my problem  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

`<input type="number" min="0" step="1" value="0" name="Prioriteit@item" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Html.TextBox("Prioriteit" + item, "0", new { @type="number", min = "0", step = "1" })
```