# Make EditorFor render decimal value as type="text" not type="number"

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-input, editorformodel

I have two properties in a model class:

```
public int? IntTest { get; set; }
public decimal? DecimalTest { get; set; }
```

Which I then render with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IntTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DecimalTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
```

I'd expected both of them to render as html inputs of type number, but the decimal one doesn't, I get:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field IntTest must be a number." id="IntTest" name="IntTest" type="number" value="" />
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field IntTest must be a number." id="DecimalTest" name="DecimalTest" type="text" value="" />
```

The decimal value is rendered as `type="text"` whereas the int is registered as `type="number"`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755560/how-to-force-razor-to-make-editorfor-to-input-number-type-for-float-variable) implies that isn't the expected behaviour so am I doing something wrong?

If that is the expected behaviour, is there any way of changing `EditorFor` to render all decimals as `type="number"`, rather than having to add `type = "number"` in the `htmlAttributes` of every decimal field?

Comment: Do you need to use EditorFor ? Did you consider using `TextBoxFor` ?

Comment: @Shyju I'm pretty sure I got the same behaviour with TextBoxFor too - should TextBoxFor generate an input with type = "number"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The html you are seeing is the default behavior. The `EditorFor()` methods use the default templates (unless you have created a custom `EditorTemplate` for the type) as defined in [TemplateHelpers.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/TemplateHelpers.cs).

For typeof `int` (and `byte` and `long`), it uses the `NumberInputTemplate`, and for typeof `decimal` it uses the `DecimalTemplate`. These templates are defined in [DefaultEditorTemplates.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DefaultEditorTemplates.cs) which are for `decimal`

```
internal static string DecimalTemplate(HtmlHelper html)
{
    if (html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue == html.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model)
    {
        html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:0.00}", html.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model);
    }
    return StringTemplate(html);
}
```

which in turn calls

```
internal static string StringTemplate(HtmlHelper html)
{
    return HtmlInputTemplateHelper(html);
}
```

and for `int`

```
internal static string NumberInputTemplate(HtmlHelper html)
{
    return HtmlInputTemplateHelper(html, inputType: "number");
}
```

Note that the `NumberInputTemplate` defines the `inputType` as `"number"` which adds the `type="number"` attribute, where as `StringTemplate` uses the default `inputType` which generates `type="text"`.

To add `type="number"` for a `decimal`, then you need to manually add the attribute, using either

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DecimalTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control"} })
```

or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DecimalTest, new { type = "number", @class = "form-control"})
```

An alternative would be to create a custom `EditorTemplate` in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Decimal.cshtml` for typeof `decimal`, for example

```
@model decimal?
@{
    var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(ViewData["htmlAttributes"]);
    if (!attributes.ContainsKey("type"))
    {
         attributes.Add("type", "number");
    }
    string formatString = ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString ?? "{0:N2}";
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, formatString , attributes)
```

and in the main view use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DecimalTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
```

Another alternative would be to create you own `HtmlHelper` extension method (say `@Html.DecimalFor(...)`) to generate the html.

Comment: That's fascinating, has opened up a whole new side of things I didn't know existed and really helped me understand the behaviour. Thanks very much for taking the time to explain it.  I hadn't realised the traditional aspnet source code was online, I'm off for a good dig around in there!

Comment: Actually, one follow on question; do you have any idea why this is the default behaviour for decimals?  Is it to allow for commas as decimal separators perhaps?

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the precision - how may decimal places to display, and if you had say 2, would you then want the step to be 0.01, which would take forever to increment via the buttons making using it a bit pointless (its not associated with the decimal separator)

Comment: Both good points - I'd already killed the spinners via CSS in my code.  I've made one change to your code by adding an if statement to check if the type attribute is already there, that means it can then be overridden from code on a case by case basis and won't error if the user has already set the type:  `if (!attributes.ContainsKey("type")) { attributes.Add("type", "number"); }` .  If you think that's a good addition by all means update your answer to include it.

Comment: @tomRedox. Updated :) - and of course there are numerous other enhancements you could make such as reading any forma string from `ModelMetadata` and applying that or a default if applicable. But out of interest, if you have removed the spinner, why use `type="number"`?

Comment: Oh that's interesting re the `ModelMetadata`, I was thinking about formatting.  There's a lot of interest in that class.  The reason for `type="number"` was primarily to make the field only accept numbers so that it was consistent with the integer fields nearby (without having to tack on additional code) and also because I think (but haven't checked yet) that by being of number type the field will then trigger the numeric keypad on mobile?

Comment: Just updated again to show how you might do that. But at some point, you start getting too much logic in the template, which is when creating a custom `HtmlHelper` extension method should be considered.