# c# how to do an action if any character string does NOT match a pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a pattern and want to empty the textbox and show a message when the input does not match the pattern.

I have tried putting the erasing line in `else`, and used a negation `!` in front of the condition.

```
   if (!Regex.IsMatch(MyTextBox.Text, ".*?[0-9].*?"))
   {
       MyTextBox.Text = "";
       MessageBox.Show("Please input only numbers");
   }
```

But both of these solution result in that if **ANY** symbol in the textbox matches the pattern gives an error when I want to `float.parse` the string later on.

Examples:

- 1234  should and does work
- A     Stops you as it should
- 1A    Doesn't stop you, but should

Comment: Just use `float.TryParse()` instead. You don't need to validate it manually and then use `float.Parse()` later on.

Comment: You could also just add type='number' to your input element, this would force this behavior without the need for the validation or message.  <input type='number'>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/33755754/3845625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(textbox.Text, "^[0-9]*$")){
....
}
```